# How to install Lubuntu-18.04 32 bit

Tags: partition, system-installation, lubuntu

i'd been trying to install lubuntu in my old laptop

Laptop is Webbook NBX8010D with specs

- Processors : Intel Atom® Processor N270 1.6 Ghz
- Ram : 1x1gb DDR2
- HDD : Samsung HM160HI

I'm creating the bootable using rufus with setting

- Partition scheme : MBR & UEFI Legacy
- File system : FAT32
- Cluster size : 16kb
- ISO Mode

The laptop come with Windows XP Home 32 bit. Installation wenth smooth until partition part where i can't partition in it. I want to format the HDD first but i don't know how. Pressing alt + f2 & alt + f3 (busybox v1.27.2 (ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3) built -in shell (ash) to find terminal or gparted or things like that but didn't find one.

Partition error is like "we have been unable to inform the kernel of the change, probably because it/they are in use. As a result, the old partition(s) will remain in use. You should reboot now before making further changes.

ERROR!!!

thank

Comment: You may check the HDD drive. Is the drive locked? Moreover if you don't know how to install it you may search for some guides online.

Comment: Idk, never experience in XP before.. but i'll check it later

Comment: Are you sure you are using a **Live** (entire system loads into RAM)? If not, Lubuntu is using your HDD, thus you can't *edit* it.

Comment: It's booting from flashdisk. When i click power button, i clicm F11 to choose boot device, then i cboose my flashdisk ( it's not UEFI )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I complete my installation by formating the HDD and everything works fine. Still a bit laggy too but better then windows XP